# WPF Stop Clipping My Image - Window (Header Area) Layout

Tags: wpf, layout, user-interface, window

I want to add a header to my Window using WPF where my header icon appears to hang outside of the header area (so the bottom is in the details area).  Something like the following:

[image: Want To Achieve]

I currently have an implementation using a Dock Panel and Grid Panels.  This looks like the following.

[image: Currently Have]

However, if I resize the image using the VS2013 designer, then the image gets cropped at the bottom of the dock panel.  I have tried ZIndex etc to get round this to no avail but I am still learning.

Here is my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Boom.AndezViews.TestWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Test Window" Height="342" Width="581">
    <DockPanel>
        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="CadetBlue"
              VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Grid x:Name="TitleHeaderGrid" Margin="10 10 0 0" ClipToBounds="False">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid x:Name="TitleHeaderTextGrid" Grid.Column="0">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                               TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Window Title" 
                               FontSize="24" Margin="0 0 10 0"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Margin="10 3 0 0"
                           TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                           Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, tation torquatos in pro, in nec commune placerat. At volumus legendos eleifend his, at quod noster ocurreret mea, unum admodum mandamus ad sea. Quod vivendum definiebas his ad." 
                           FontSize="12"/>
                </Grid>
                <Border Grid.Column="1" Background="Transparent" Height="109" Margin="0 0 0 0"
                       Width="109" >
                    <Image Source="/Resources/critical_error_icon_trans256.png" RenderSize="10 15">

                    </Image>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>

        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="60">
            <Button>
                <TextBlock>Close Me</TextBlock>
            </Button>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Background="ForestGreen">
            <Grid Margin="20 10 0 0">
                <TextBlock>Enter some details:</TextBlock>
                <ScrollViewer Margin="0 20 10 10">
                    <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True"></TextBox>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

This is like the following design:

[image]

Like I said, I am still learning WPF so would appreciate some input to the overall laying out of the window.  I am using a Dock Panel as I thought this would be the best way to make the header stick to the top internal part of the window - is this the best way in WPF?

Also, I want to achieve the answer for my main question which is how can I get the window to appear as in the first screenshot.  Why is there clipping (if that is the correct WPF term) occurring and how can I get the icon to appear out of the header dock panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see. Please try this code whether it satisfies your Needs:

```
<Window x:Class="Test1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" >
<Grid x:Name="TitleHeaderGrid" Margin="10 10 0 0" ClipToBounds="False">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border Background="#FF24C5C5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Window Title" 
                FontSize="24" Margin="0 0 10 0"/>
    <TextBlock Margin="10 40 0 0"
                TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, tation torquatos in pro, in nec commune placerat. At volumus legendos eleifend his, at quod noster ocurreret mea, unum admodum mandamus ad sea. Quod vivendum definiebas his ad." 
                FontSize="12"/>

    <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="#FF2BA236"></Border>

    <Grid Margin="20 0 0 0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="2">
        <TextBlock>Enter some details:</TextBlock>
        <ScrollViewer Margin="0 20 10 10">
            <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True"></TextBox>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>

    <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" Fill="#FFFF0000" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="110" Width="109" />

    <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="Close Me"/>
</Grid>
```

For testing purposes I just replaced your Image by a red rectangle.

Comment: +1 Thanks gomi42 that works for me.  I guess the dock panel will not work for the scenario I had?  I've accepted the answer although I was hoping to make it work with the DockPanel.

Comment: Right, with DockPanel controls cannot overlap multiple rows or columns.

Answer (score 0):

Your image is clipped within the first row. Did you try to add `Grid.RowSpan="2"` to the border that holds your Image?

Comment: I tried RowSpans on various things.  But the way I have designed it is that there are only the RowDefinitions on the Grid that holds the text which is contained in it's own Grid (TitleHeaderTextGrid).  The main Grid (TitleHeaderGrid) only has column definitions which contains the TitleHeaderTextGrid and Border around the Image - so I didn't think RowSpan would be affective.  It still crops with the RowSpan set and the Margin with a bottom of -21 for example.